# What class is inside a non-character library call in R?

Tags: r

In R we can load packages with:

```
library(knitr)
```

or

```
library("knitr")
```

In `?library`, it says this argument can be a character or a name. However:

```
is.name(knitr)
Error: object 'knitr' not found
class(knitr)
Error: object 'knitr' not found
```

Also complicating this is when a package contains a function that is also the name of the package:

```
library(data.table)
class(data.table)
[1] "function"
library(data.table) #returns nothing
```

Somehow, it knows not to pass the function `data.table` into the library function, but instead interpret it as a call to load the package (I think). How does R handle this?

Comment: Google `non-standard evaluation in R` .

Comment: see section 1.6 of data.table faq https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.pdf

Comment: `library()` is a special function. How functions choose to handle parameter can vary by function so it's impossible to describe how every parameter for every function works. Can you make your question more specific? Is this really just about the `library()` function?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck that was very helpful thanks. I like the overall concept, but I'm not sure I like how its used in this way. Much appreciated

Comment: `is.name(quote(knitr))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant lines of `library()` say

```
if (!character.only) 
        package <- as.character(substitute(package))
```

We can make our own little function (`library()` is complicated!) to explore how this works:

```
tmpf <- function(x) {
   str(substitute(x))
}
tmpf(knitr)
## symbol knitr
```

We can make an equivalent thing using `quote()`:

```
str(quote(knitr))
## symbol knitr
```

But passing it to `tmpf()` doesn't preserve its form, because of the `substitute()` call:

```
tmpf(quote(knitr))
## language quote(knitr)
```

If we were to put `eval(substitute(x))` into `tmpf()`, we would get "object knitr not found" when we passed `knitr`, and a symbol-object `knitr` when we passed `quote(knitr)`.

The `character.only` argument to `library()` is what you use if you want to pass a string variable whose *value* is `"knitr"`;

```
str_var <- "knitr"
library(str_var,character.only=TRUE)
```

Comment: Great example and explanation, thanks. I don't really see what the benefit to `package <- as.character(substitute(package))` is from a usage standpoint. Why not just only take character arguments? Anyway, not really in scope for my question.

Comment: I agree that this particular "feature" of `library()` is/was a bad idea. I think the original idea was that it was convenient for users to be able to use either convention. In fact (IMO) it's just (1) confusing, because the non-standard evaluation paradigm is inconsistently applied across base-R functions, (2) adds to code complexity. In Python [there should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - a useful maxim.